# Delays the windows shut down for a minute

Tags: windows

Is there a software or option that delays and ask if i really want to shut down.

I saw this in MacOS:
[image]

I would like to have something similar for Windows.

Comment: How do you shutdown the PC? Do you initiate that yourself or is it done by circumstances unknown to you. AFAIK, Windows does not have such a feature and implementing one could be quite hard (at least what I know about it; I'm a programmer).

Comment: Well actually i thought about digging into it and try to write something like that.

Comment: I made a small program to automate shutdown: [Simple Scheduler](https://gunay.name.tr/eng/). There's an option "Warn before action".

Comment: thank you. I am searching more for an automated solution. and not for a script that does that after a certain time. But It looks like a nice software

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via command line.

For example you can shutdown after 10 minutes with the following command:

```
shutdown -s -t 600
```

Timeout is in seconds. 10 minutes = 600 seconds. A window will popup like this:

[image]

Sorry, I only have an Italian Windows right now.

To cancel the shutdown just write:

```
shutdown -a
```

You will also get a notification.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown

Comment: Yea i know. i was more searching for some automatism...